# Is the syntax for here documents in Ruby 1.9.3 different?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently learning Ruby, and I've come across a weird snag in the tutorial I'm using. I'm using [this exercise](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex9.html) from Learn Ruby The Hard Way, and it keeps producing a syntax error, and I can't figure out why.

The code I'm trying to use is

```
    puts <<-'HERE'
        There's something going on here.
        With the PARAGRAPH thing
        We'll be able to type as much as we like.
        Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
    HERE
```

But, it always produces the following syntax error

```
ex9.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
We'll be able to type as much as we like.
     ^
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm using TextWrangler, and *TextWrangler* parses it as a block quote, but Ruby is not.

Comment: Works fine on my system (1.9.3)

Comment: I don't see any errors. How you run the code?

Comment: I just ran it on the command line! Just as ruby ex9.rb

Comment: Probably an encoding problem.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it's a problem with how TextWrangler encodes it? Since it doesn't produce the same errors in irb.

Comment: This error will also be caused when there is a space on either side of the `-` in `<<-'HERE'`. Anna, try running `ruby -w ex9.rb`, and you probably will see some warnings?

Comment: "ex9.rb:9: warning: `<<' after local variable is interpreted as binary operator // ex9.rb:9: warning: even though it seems like here document"
there we go.

Comment: Yup, thats the problem. Spaces. Quick, let me add this as an answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it does not seem like it in the code snippet you posted, you probably did have a space on both or one side of the `-` in `<<-'HERE'`.

If you do, you will likely see warnings like this:

```
test.rb:1: warning: `<<' after local variable is interpreted as binary operator
test.rb:1: warning: even though it seems like here document
test.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
        We'll be able to type as much as we like.
             ^
```

Comment: I tried added spaces and then deleting them again, but -w still produces that same error. I think CodeGnome is right that there's something in the encoding that's putting a space there? But I can't figure out how fix it.

Comment: Edit the file in vi/vim/nano, ensure there are no spaces, then try running again.

Comment: And hopefully, you are editing the same file you are running - it can happen~

Comment: Try `ruby -W2 ex9.rb` - that might give you some more warnings?

Comment: no, it still just gave me the warning about interpreting the << as a binary operator

Comment: Create a new file, in vim, and type it out by hand instead of copy-paste. It is a problem with the space, but why your editor is adding spaces is beyond me.

Comment: Yeah, that ended up being exactly the problem. Guess I'll have to just use vim. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It works for me with ruby-1.9.3-p194:

```
[1] pry(main)> puts <<-'HERE'
[1] pry(main)*         There's something going on here.
[1] pry(main)*         With the PARAGRAPH thing
[1] pry(main)*         We'll be able to type as much as we like.
[1] pry(main)*         Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
[1] pry(main)*     HERE
        There's something going on here.
        With the PARAGRAPH thing
        We'll be able to type as much as we like.
        Even 4 lines if we want, or 5, or 6.
=> nil
```

I would suspect hidden characters or encoding issues. Check your locale, or try the `--encoding` flag when starting the interpreter.

Comment: I tried typing the same code into irb and it worked just fine. I'll check to see if there's something wrong with how I copy-pasted it. Would the --encoding flag be used by typing 'ruby --encoding ex9.rb'?

Comment: The flag expects an argument, such as `ruby --encoding utf-8`. You can also read ruby(1) or http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings/ to see if this addresses your issue.

Comment: I already got the more specific answer, but I'll have to read up on it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem, turns out the bottom file marker "HERE" in the above example was not against the left margin (in notebook anyway).

Any spaces in front it, or tabs and it refused point blank to work.